# Ubuntu on Virtualbox says 20 GB used when actual size of VDI is only 8 GB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I have a Guest Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows 7 Host. I've set the VDI limit to 20GB dynamically allocated. My Ubuntu boots to say there is zero space left in the system and sure enough `df` shows that this is indeed (nearly) so.

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPRGR.png)

I decided to extend the size of the VDI, but then I noticed that the actual file size of the VDI is only 7.57 GB. If so, why does Ubuntu say my space is used up ? How can I rectify this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is due to the disk being dynamically allocated and that you're only using 7.57 GB at present with a maximum of 20 GB allowed.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot the VM with a partitioning tool like PartedMagic, or gparted and increase the size of the partition that way.  The extra space will show up as unpartitioned space.  So the space is there is it just unpartitioned.

Comment: Please see this screenshot of df. My sda1 seems to have used up all the 20GB. If it were unpartitioned, do you still suppose this would show the same result?

Comment: find /  -size +900M  |more
Run this command with progressively smaller sizes and see if you can identify what is using all the space.